# sbt value not found addSbtPlugin when installing onejar plugin

Tags: plugins, jar, sbt, executable-jar

I'm trying to [install the one-jar sbt plugin](https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar) but am getting the following error:

```
sbt/project/plugins/plugins.sbt:5: error: not found: value addSbtPlugin
addSbtPlugin("com.github.retronym" % "sbt-onejar" % "0.6")
```

Here is the relevant contents of my `sbt/build.sbt` file:

```
seq(com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings: _*)

name := "dsg_nlp"

version := "0.11"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.6.1" % "test" )
libraryDependencies += "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"

traceLevel in run := 0

fork in run := true

javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xmx7G", "-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,depth=12", "-server", "-enableassertions")

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-optimize")

mainClass in (one-jar, Compile, packageBin) := Some("Test")
```

And the contents of my `project/plugins/plugins.sbt` file:

```
resolvers += "retronym-releases" at "http://retronym.github.com/repo/releases"

resolvers += "retronym-snapshots" at "http://retronym.github.com/repo/snapshots"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.retronym" % "sbt-onejar" % "0.6")
```

Comment: Which version of sbt are you running?

Comment: I'm running `version := "0.11"`

Comment: The code you posted above is working for me. I can't replicate your problem. I was using sbt 0.11.2.

Comment: @Steffen -- I updated it to version 0.11.2, but I still have the same issue. Are your files in the same locations as mine?

Comment: I just pushed my test code into a public git repository. Maybe this helps. See https://github.com/stefri/Test1.

Comment: @Steffen -- thanks! Different structure than I have: my `project` is under `sbt`. Where do you run the `sbt` command (`Test1` or `sbt` or `project`)? If I move things to match what you have, I get the same error when running `sbt` from `Test1`.

Comment: I've uploaded a running sample of my proposed answer in the "revised01" branch. This sample also uses one-jar 0.7 but it does run with 0.6, too. See https://github.com/stefri/Test1/tree/revised01

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following changes to the code above:

- Make sure you have only one setting per line. So split

```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.6.1" % "test" )

   libraryDependencies += "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"
```

into two lines.

- The last line should read

  `mainClass in oneJar := Some("Test")`

  if you want to use another `mainClass` for the oneJar-Plugin. If it's the same as in the compile scope. You may as well write this as

  `mainClass in Compile := Some("Test")`

  but do not specifiy both.

Your project directory structure should look like this:

```
Project-Root /
 |-- build.sbt
 |-- project/plugins.sbt
```

the actual names of the sbt-files don't matter they just have to end in .sbt.